# BIRT and Orbeon

Tags: xml, xpath, orbeon

We are using Orbeon (3.9) in a standard config. What we are trying to do is create a Eclipse BIRT report of the data and form defenition.

We managed to get the data.xml in our report, but are unable to combine the data.xml and form definition (xhtml) so we can get an output which gives the same as the input on a form.

Can somebody point us in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know anything about BIRT, but let's see if I can still help. How do you access the `data.xml`? Are you doing this through the REST persistence API? (I imagine you're referring to the data collected by the form?) If you are, you should be able to access the form definition in the same way.

Comment: Thanx.. Yes we use an URL (with parameter) to get the right entry (data) of the form. example : http://server:8080/orbeon-CE/exist/rest/db/application/formname/data/" + params["ID"].value + "/data.xml"    Problem is that I can't combine the form data and xhtml nicely in a report. Is there a function to combine the two files into one xml? We have problems with a check-box control. How to combine the data, with the label of the selection

Comment: So you're saying that you can make one HTTP request to get the form definition, another HTTP request to get the form data, but would like to have one request that returns both? Sorry, but the persistence API doesn't do that. But it would be simple enough for you to write a service that does this, wouldn't it?